# Make all files private when using django s3 file storage

Tags: django, amazon-s3, django-storage

When using the S3BotoStorage file storage from Django-storages (`DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto.S3BotoStorage'`), files are created as publicly viewable.  How do I make files only visible to users I explicitly give URLs to?  I know boto has ways of generating temporarily valid urls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the following in settings.py:

```
AWS_DEFAULT_ACL = "private"
```

Then, make sure the following settings are their default values (you can either set them as follows or remove them from your settings.py):

```
AWS_QUERYSTRING_AUTH = True
AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN = None
```

You should also use the [block all public access setting](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/access-control-block-public-access.html) on the bucket.